# Does Islam permit writing fictional stories?

Tags: halal-haram, lying

I searched the internet and found many fatwas that writing fiction (if it adheres to sharia) is allowed. But i still have a doubt because of this hadith:

> Woe to the one who speaks with lies to make the people laugh, woe to him, woe to him.

So, what is the ruling concerning fiction?

Answer (score 1):

Fictional stories are a little different than just idle joke telling because they can be used for **educational** reasons. Fatawa saying they are permissible likely were referring to fictional stories that serve this purpose. (Even cartoons are allowed for young children for educational reasons, despite being 'images').

If the above does not suffice for you, then it's an Islamic principle to leave that "gray area" ie, doubtful matters. Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) said about doubtful matters: "whoever leaves it to protect his religion and his honor, then he will be safe" - [Tirmidhi (1205)](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/14/1).

Answer (score 0):

It is not haram! Telling lies to make a person laugh means that the person doesn't know that you are telling something not true and they think you are telling them something true. It's like making a joke to someone and they think what you are saying is true, and you're not telling them that what you are saying is not true. This is not like fiction, which the reader understands that what is being written is not true from the beginning. If they understand that what you are saying is not true and is fiction, it's not a lie. Don't listen to what anyone says. I am a Muslim fiction author. You can find my fiction books on Amazon.com under the pen name Gabriel Bacopa. Everything in Islam is halal unless stated otherwise. There were many great stories written by Muslims in the Islamic golden age. 1001 nights as an example. Aladdin, sindbad etc. were all written by Muslims. According to the Fiqh book Reliance of the Traveller, writing fiction that has praiseworthy lessons is actually something that God will reward one for.